# grails (gorm) set contains and persists duplicates

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I don't quite understand what is going on in my code right now.  From what I understand, a groovy set does not contain duplicates.  However, I am seeing duplicates in a set and also seeing duplicates persisted to the database.  Although when retrieved from the database, the duplicates are not in the set.

I have two classes (some properties removed for brevity):

```
class EntityType {
    static hasMany = [attributes: Attribute]
}

class Attribute {
    String keyname
}
```

In my service, I pass in a jsonarray of attributes that are added to the EntityType using `type.addToAttributes(attr)`.  If I execute the same call more than once, duplicates are added to the Set.  And when persisting, the duplicates are persisted.  However, when I retrieve the Set from the database, the Set is retrieved without any duplicates.  So the end result is it doesn't seem to hurt anything other than filling up the database table with unnecessary data.

What am I missing about Sets?

EDIT:  Here's something odd I just noticed.  The duplicates are not created for all of the attributes.  Only n-1 duplicates are created.  When iterating through the attribute jsonarry, the first attribute is not duplicated, but each one after that is.  So if my array was {a:1,b:2,c:3} it would only create duplicates of b and c.

Comment: How do you create the `attr` instance? Its look like you have multiple `Attribute` instances with the same `keyname` ...

Comment: I have an attribute service that returns either the existing Attribute by the same name or creates a new one with the name.  What's odd is that new Attributes are not created and persisted, only the new relationship (EntityType-Attribute) is created with the existing Attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.  I ended up having to override the `int hashCode()` and `boolean equals(Object o)` methods as such:

```
@Override
int hashCode() {
    return keyname.hashCode() + id.hashCode()
}

@Override
boolean equals(Object o) {
    Attribute other = o as Attribute
    return keyname.equals(other.keyname) && id.equals(other.id)
}
```

While I don't really like this because it forces me to update these methods if I add new properties, it works for now.

Comment: I am having the same problem with Grails using both TreeSet and LinkedHashSet, but using id in your equals and hashCode methods violates the contract -- hashCode and equals are supposed to be based on immutable values for the life of the Collection. See http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html?page=2. I am still trying to figure out how to avoid duplicate references (literally, hashCode, equals, compareTo and even the JVM memory reference denote they are identical) in my sets, but I don't think this is it.

Comment: Also, depending on the id would tell you that an unsaved attribute with the same keyname as a saved attribute is not equal to the saved. That can lead to duplicates actually being persisted in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with aiolos that the most obvious reason is that you have multiple attributes with the same name.

you can prevent this making keyname unique

```
class Attribute {
    String keyname

    static constraints = {
        keyname unique:true
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not multiple attributes with the same name, at least not in the database.  When the relationship rows are persisted, they are truly duplicate rows. ie. several rows of entitytype 1 and attribute 3